# I have this error in my service layer: Cannot implicitly convert type 'PokemonCard.Data.Card' to 'int'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8

I'm doing a little project for fun just so I can practice my n-tier web api's (it's a Pokémon card database). I'm currently working on the service layer, specifically in the CardService class, and I am running into an error in the update section of the CardService. This is the code that I have written:

```
namespace PokemonCard.Services
{
     public class CardService
     {
          public bool UpdateCard (CardEdit model)
          {
               using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
               {
                    var entity = ctx.Cards
                                    .Single(e => e.Name == model.Name && e.OwnerId == _userId);
                    var card = ctx.Cards
                                  .Single(e => e.Id == entity.Id);

                    entity.Name = model.Name;
                    entity.Id = card;
                    entity.SetId = model.SetId;
                    entity.TypeOfCard = model.TypeOfCard;
                    entity.IsHolo = model.IsHolo;
                    entity.ArtStyle = model.ArtStyle;
                    entity.Rarity = model.Rarity;

                    return ctx.SaveChanges() == 1;
               }
          }
     }       
}
```

On this line of code:

```
entity.Id = card;
```

I get an error

> CS0029:Cannot implicitly convert type 'PokemonCard.Data.Card' to 'int'

Can anyone help? How to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What type is `Card` and why are you trying to use it as an `int`? Is there a property on `Card` you're meaning to use?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Card is a table in my Data layer

Comment: So if Card cannot be explicitly or implicitly converted to an int, you need to think about what property on Card you're meaning to use.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'm trying to use the int labeled Id in my Card class. I guess I am not quite sure how to call that specific property. Or I am misunderstanding what it is you are saying. I am actually going through a bootcamp, essentially, for coding and all this is rather new to me (about 2 weeks with api's specifically)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
ctx
    .Cards
    .Single(e => e.Id == entity.Id);
```

returns a single instance of type "Card".

entity.Id is of type "int" but is being assigned a value of type "Card".  It should likely be:

```
entity.Id = card.Id;
```

Also, I find it helpful to use "SingleOrDefault" instead of simply "Single" and to account for the null value that is returned in the case of no match in the database.